# To Execute multiple Test fragment gradually using multiple module controller in Single thread group

Tags: testing, controller, jmeter, fragment, jmeter-5.0

I want to execute multiple Test fragment one by one in single thread group for that I have created multiple test fragment and for each Test fragment I have separate module controller that I am selecting using switch controller, but while executing a test entire thread group duration is getting consumed in one module controller. Others module controllers are not getting window. PFA Jmeter elements structure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGxD3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using simplified version of test plan:

[image]

so my expectation is that something is wrong with your ForEach Controller and/or Switch Controller.

Given the nature of the [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) I don't think you need to have these 2 guys at all (unless there is a custom complex selection logic which I'm not aware of)

If you need further assistance you need to show

- ForEach Controller and Switch Controller configuration
- Schematic view of your Test Plan (Tools -> Generate Schematic View)
- The values of JMeter Variables used in the ForEach and Switch Controllers for at least 2 iterations (can be obtained using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script))
- [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)